# Java searching file name from the one folder

Tags: java, filtering, filenames

I am studying Java and I am not really sure the way to searching file.  I would like to build the function which returning file names ( the files name should begin with `star` and end with `.txt`)

For example, in the folder we have Java source file with some file.  For example, files:

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- 4.txt
- start.txt
- star.txt
- onstart.txt
- starton.txt
- myjava.java

Then I would like to get the `start.txt`, `star.txt` & `starton.txt`

I was looking for the `FilenameFilter` but I wasn't able to find to good way to find file.  Does any one know the way to find files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// You'll need this import: import java.io.File;

File folder = new File("C:/Folder_Location");
// gets you the list of files at this folder
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
// loop through each of the files looking for filenames that match
for(int i = 0; i < listOfFile.length; i++){
    String filename = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    if(filename.startsWith("Stuff") && listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith("OtherStuff")){
        // do something with the filename
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated above, File(".") is a shortcut to the current directory.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the easiest way is to simple use [`File#listFiles(FileFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29), something like

```
File[] fileList = new File("/path/to/search").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks is there anyway that i dont need to use path ? like "/path/to/search"

Comment: Well I depends. File is an abstract concept of path on the OS file system (pointing to a file or directory). You could use File("."), but that's just a short cut to the current directory, or you can use relative paths

Answer (score 0):

`File#getName() should return a`String`, then use:

```
filename.startsWith(...);
filename.endsWith(...);
```