# Searching a directory for a file name

Tags: java

How to search a particular folder for a file name, that is input by the user. In my program the file is an excel spreadsheet. So if i basically use:

```
Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName = kbReader.nextLine();
```

How would i search and open the corresponding file with the name `fileName`.

Comment: You could either use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) and search that resulting array or [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) with an own `FilenameFilter`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java searching file name from the one folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216432/java-searching-file-name-from-the-one-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expression to match your file name like `filename.matches("*"+expectedfilename+"*.xls"))` on List of file names taken from directory.

```
String fileName = null;
File folder = new File("your/directory/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
         fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();

         if(fileName.matches("*"+expectedfilename+"*.xls"))){  // put regex here
               // do your code here and 
               // if you want to open do operation on file then file object
               File file = listOfFiles[i];
         }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: I think he wants to search for the file in disk. This is not an answer that he looking for

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    File dir = new File("F:/");
    File[] allFileName = dir.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < allFileName.length; i++) {
        String filename = allFileName[i].getName()
        if (allFileName[i].isFile()) {
            if (filename.endsWith(".xls"))
            System.out.println("This is a excel file with name " + filename);
        } 
    }
```